# When I run this function the returns and prints don't seem to be doing anything

Tags: python

```
def position_assign(position):
    
    player = True
    
    acceptable_values = range(1,9)

    while player == True:
        if position in acceptable_values:
            
            for index in range(len(row1 or row2 or row3)):
                if row1[index] == position:
                    row1[index] = 'X'
                    player = False
                elif row2[index] == position:
                    row2[index] = 'X'
                    player = False
                elif row3[index] == position:
                    row3[index] = 'X'
                    player = False
                    
    return "Now its Os turn."
        
    while not player:
        if position in acceptable_values:
            for index in range(len(row1 or row2 or row3)):
                    if row1[index] == position:
                        row1[index] = 'O'
                        player = True
                    elif row2[index] == position:
                        row2[index] = 'O'
                        player = True
                    elif row3[index] == position:
                        row3[index] = 'O'
                        player = True
                        
    return "Now its Xs turn."
                    
                    
    print('Test Complete')
```

I'd like to use the boolean variable to establish what input the user will use. X or O given that they've picked which one they'd like to use in another function that will assign player to True or False. I can get the replace to work fine in the posted function, but the returns and prints are not working.

Comment: You haven't "run" the function because you haven't called it

Comment: Also, `print('Test Complete')` is never reached because it's after the `return` statement. In fact, the whole second half of the function is never reached.

Comment: Yeah, or what @mkrieger1 suggested. Maybe you did actually run the function but it then just `return`s a string literal, and then nothing else happens - you break out of the function

Answer (score -2):

Please call the function position_assign(pass the parameter) and call it outside the indentation of the functions also instead of return say print().

Comment: This is still speculation and there's at least one way for the function to exit without printing anything

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).